# Android Listview jumps on change in adapter content

Tags: android

I am using a scroll listener to detect the end of the Listview.The list initially has 20 items. When the end is reached I populate the list with 10 more items from the DB. At the same time I remove the top 10 items which aren't visible. Since I delete the top 10 items the newly added items are shown on screen and the scroll listener detects end of list and populates 10 more items. So my two problems are

1) How do I stop the position of the item I am currently viewing from changing ?

2) How to prevent the onScrollListener from being called multiple times ?

I guess if you could help me with the first problem, the second would automatically be taken care of.

By the way ,I call notifyDatasetchanged to update the content of the adapter. Kindly help, and thanks.

Comment: probably the easiest way would be not removing the first entries at all: with a properly designed usage and recycling of item renderers it won't make your application less smoother, but could be confusing for the end-user.

Comment: @rekaszeru  but the adapter size will increase a lot. I have a very huge database containing thousands of entries which I'd have to show on the list.

Comment: I understand your concern, but you should keep in mind, that those items may / will be fetched on demand, and if you are doing a good job, you will need no more than 15-20 item renderers for display them: once one is scrolled out of the screen, it will be recycled on the other side. This is the part that may cause bad user experience, if not handled correctly, not populating a plain `ArrayList` on demand with even tens of thousands of items. Please watch this presentation by `Romain Guy` about efficient android gui, I'm sure you'll find it helpful! www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA

Comment: Have you tried to call invalidateViews() on the ListView?

Comment: Why do you delete the previous items? The user is unable to go back and check this items. You can try this implementation of an endless List:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

There is no problem showing a lot of listitems, if you implement a good adapter, you can reuse the views.

Comment: @Chronos I refetch the deleted items when I move to the top and delete the non visible items below. Wont I be getting an OutOfMemory exception if I go on adding items to the list ?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/ try this